# How to refresh Flasks automatically

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a CSV file which keeps updating every 30 seconds. I'd want my app.py in flask to read that file every 30 seconds so that the webpage stays updated. How can i do it ?

```
open_minute = "final_minute_"+name+".pickle"
file = open(open_minute,"rb")
final_minute = pickle.load(file)
labels_minute = [i for i in final_minute['Hour_Minutes'].values]
```

I need my app.py in flask to keep reading the open_minute file every 30 seconds.

Comment: Use some background task(or cron ) to read  a file in every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up a function that updates the global variable every thirty seconds, it would look like this:

```py
def update()
   while True:
      time.sleep(30)
      # Do tasks here.

@app.before_request
async def before():
   update()
```